# How to Start/ Run Angular application with pm2 in aws ec2

Tags: angular

I have configuration in directory /etc/nginx/conf.d

`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/owner/dist/browser;
    server_name stagingapp.company.com;


location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I Built the app from my local system and pushed to Git.
Then pulled the same from Ec2 Server from app directory.
Now I want to run the application. Do we have any command for this with PM2.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine with the application.

cd /var/www/my-demo-app
ng build --prod --build-optimizer

*Also check,
sudo apt-get update
sudo npm update

Comment: Hi, I already built from my local and upload to GitHub. Then pulled from EC2 Server directory.